# Android Trucaller SDK needs a argument in getProfile

Tags: android

`TruecallerSDK.getInstance().getUserProfile();`

The above line is not working in Android Studio. Its the exact line copied from the Truecaller official docs. They that getUserProfile does not take any argument but when i write it like this, it doesn't work.

Please help! It requires a `FragmentActivity` or a `Fragment` method.
And i am writing this code in my `onCreate` in `MainActivity`